# Как задавать в этом случае префабам разные конечные координаты

Tags: c#, unity3d

При использовании написаного мной кода, при смене конечной точки координат endposition меняется движение и заспавненого раньше префаба, что логично, но я не знаю как этого избежать. Мне же нужно, чтобы разные префабы двигались по разному, и движение не менялось, а задавалось только один раз при спавне. Первая часть кода тут, это первый скрипт что и задает точки
`

```
void Update()
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, ray.direction * rayDistance);

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
    {
        if (hit.transform.gameObject.tag == "Base" & Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) & Check == false)
        {
            Check = true;
            CheckBase = (hit.transform.gameObject);
            startPosition = hit.transform.position;
        }

            if (hit.transform.gameObject.tag == "EnemyBase" & Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) & Check == true)
            {
                CheckBase2 = (hit.transform.gameObject);
                endPosition = hit.transform.position;
}
```

А вот вторая часть, это скрипт самого префаба

```
public void FixedUpdate()
{
    startPosition = ClickBase.startPosition;
    endPosition = ClickBase.endPosition;
    progress2 += step2 / 10000;
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, endPosition, progress2);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Update` выполняется на каждом кадре, `FixedUpdate` при каждой итерации по расчету физики. Оба этих метода вызываются все время пока у всас существует объект на сцене.

Когда вы спауните объект вы обычно создаете экземпляр нового объекта из префаба, у вас так? Если да, то задание начальных значений можно делать в `Start`. Если же у вас несколько созданных заранее объектов и вы берете их из стеков, то лучше делать расчет в момент появления их на сцене, например в `OnEnabled`

Не очень понятно почему у вас на спаун объектах код отличается от префаба?

Comment: Не понял, что именно не понятно? Да, я понимаю что лучше использовать "Start", но проблема в тому, что конечные координаты всё равно меняться будут для всех прехабов, а мне нужно чтобы они были для одного прехаба заданы раз и навсегда, как например получается с "SerializedField" при использовании его с переменною, но так не получеться, старт нельзя использовать, ведь координаты берутся при использовании самого рейкаста, то есть, обновляются по ходу дела.

Comment: Я понял, я просто вынес старт, и всё получилось, большое спасибо, проблема так просто решалась, а я тупил)